# How to solve the error of Postgresql Client not installed on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Just install the Postgresql on Ubuntu 18.04 and having the error of PostgreSQL client

```
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. 
Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

I tried all the solutions that are on the StackOverflow and other forums but not succeed to solve the error

Following are the solutions that I tried

```
1. psql --cluster 10/apps [other arguments]
when I try the first solution it give me the error
Error: Invalid version 10 specified with --cluster


2. psql -p 5432


3. sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-10
when try the third solution it shows the following 
postgresql-client-10 is already the newest version (10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04).



4. gedit ~/.bashrc
PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH 
export PATH
```

Can someone tell what the exact solution to solve the error.

Comment: This isn’t really a SO question since it’s not about programming, but did you do as the message says? Or what were the “all solutions” you tried?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I updated the question with the solutions that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd solution is almost there, make sure to run `sudo apt-get install postgresql-10` too.